# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0) when starting celery worker

Tags: python, windows, celery

I used the following command to start a celery worker on Windows:

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery worker -l info
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Comment: I hope so. adding --pool is workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Windows doesn't support the celery parallel processing.
2. Adding --pool=solo is workaround to run the celery worker in windows.

> celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --pool=solo -l info

Comment: Try installing gevent. pip install gevent and run 
celery -A <module> worker -l info -P gevent